# Semantic Action Boost

Tags: c++, boost-spirit

This is taken from Boost Spirit ( a very watered down version )

```
template <typename Iterator>
    struct calculator : qi::grammar<Iterator, int(), ascii::space_type>
    {
        calculator() : calculator::base_type(expression)
        {
            qi::_val_type _val;
            qi::_1_type _1;
            qi::uint_type uint_;

            expression = term >> *('+' >> term)| ('-' >> term);
            term = uint_[&term_printer]


        qi::rule<Iterator, int(), ascii::space_type> term, expression;
    };
}
```

Now, normally, when you want to make use of semantic action, you'd write something like

```
expression = term >> *('+' >> term[&my_printer] | ('-' >> term[&my_other_printer]);
```

...

Now, let's say that when an instance of qi::rule term is found while parsing, there is a call to some other function term_printer(). Then, my_printer() will output whatever it's supposed to AFTER term_printer(). My question is, does anyone know of a way to make the call to my_printer() BEFORE term_printer(), upon the discovery of a '+' char (in this specific example)?

Some background if you are unfamiliar:
http://boost-spirit.com/distrib/spirit_1_8_3/libs/spirit/doc/semantic_actions.html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You'll have to attach an action to the parser that is responsible for the `+`. Since a `char` is not a Spirit parser (making `'+'[my_parser]` invalid) this requires you to create the Spirit parser explicitly instead of relying on the shorthand notation. The shorthand notation is syntax sugar for `qi::lit`, so:

```
//                     vvvvvvvvvvvv-- interesting part
expression = term >> *(qi::lit('+')[my_printer] >> term) | ('-' >> term);
```

The `lit` parser has no attribute, so `my_printer` has to be callable as `my_printer()` for this to work.

Comment: Ah, I had considered using qi::lit for a minute, but was at my wits end by then. Let me give it a go, but looks like it should work.

Comment: Also, is there a reason can pass it in as [my_printer] and [&my_printer] and they both still work?

Comment: I assume that `my_printer` is a function (and not a lambda or function object or so, for which `&my_printer` would not work). Functions can be converted to function pointer prvalues ([conv.func] in the standard), and this happens in the call to the parser's `operator[]`. The mechanism is quite similar to the way arrays decay to pointers to their first arguments, except that functions decay to pointers to themselves and that there are some extra rules for overloaded functions.